# USB Connection between Android and USB OTG Device

Tags: android, usb

We are trying to etablish a USB Connection between a Nexus S and a FRDM-KL25Z, for this we are looking into USB OTG connection.

The FRDM-KL25Z is USB OTG-ready and is using a different energy-source than the USB port. Now the Nexus S doesn't support USB OTG with regular firmware. Is it still possible in this case to have connection over USB?